# How to let VLC Media Library show the contents of an added folder?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Here is what I did:

- Enabled Media Library in Tools|Preferences|All|Playlist
  [image]
- Added a Videos folder to the Media Library
  [image]

However, the folder is not clickable. So the Media Library seems to contain just the folder without the contents.

If I go to the web interface, then I can see the Videos folder under the Media Library, but it is not expandable and hence it is impossible to actually select any movie from it.
[image]

BTW, the My Videos location is the same Videos folder, as you can see it also appears empty in the web interface.

In short, I do not get it. What is the purpose of adding a folder? Isn't adding a folder supposed to automatically add the files under the folder? If not, then is there a way to add a folder to VLC such that any new files in it are automatically exposed in the web interface?

I am using VLC 2.1.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same problem recently and found the solution from [VLC forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=115679#p399151).  Look like there is a bug in "demux=any" setting (in vlc\vlcrc file), after remark it and restart VLC, folder work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Around Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10, VLC [updated to 3.0.1-3build1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/vlc), and now I have to use:

```
vlc --recursive expand .
```

so that `vlc` will search for all music files in the given directory recursively.

Without that, it just loops over music files in the current directory when I do next track in random mode.